# Windows message loop

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl

Theres some reason for this code not reach the first else?
I got it exactly the same from vairous sources. Than I did my own encapsulation. Everything goes fine. Window is created, messages are treated, events are generated to keyborad input in the client area, the gl canvas works fine (when I force it to draw).

The only problem is that message loop never  leaves the first if. :/
I'm really stuck.

```
while (!done)                                       
{
    if (::PeekMessage (&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)                 
        {
            done = TRUE;                            
        }
        else                                        
        {
            ::TranslateMessage (&msg);              
            ::DispatchMessage (&msg);               
        }
    }
    else                                        
    {
        // Code is never reaching this!
        draw ();
        ::SwapBuffers(hDC);
        idle ();
    }
}
return msg.wParam;
```

Comment: Obviously something it posting new messages into the queue while Translate/Dispatch is done. You should just list all messages retrieved and deduce what message it is and why it appears.

Comment: Using spy i got a hard flow of WM_PAINT with hdc 0. No idea how this is being generated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your case the message queue must never be empty - why? Well it depends on what the rest of your program is doing.  Some possibilities:

1. Your code is posting new messages to the queue in a manner such that the queue doesn't get empty.  I'd suggest logging out the message ids as they are handled.
2. You aren't handling paint messages - from msdn:
   "The PeekMessage function normally does not remove WM_PAINT messages from the queue. WM_PAINT messages remain in the queue until they are processed. However, if a WM_PAINT message has a NULL update region, PeekMessage does remove it from the queue."

Hope this helps.

[Edit]
To handle WM_PAINT either call BeginPaint and EndPaint or forward to DefWindowProc

Comment: looks like thats the problem. But, the my MainWndProc is returning 0 from WM_PAINT. What I know is that every message you treat, you return 0. So, in theory, no message should be left.

Comment: He's handling WM_PAINT because he's seeing things appearing.

Comment: Added this code and it start to work as expected. But would like to have some explanation if possible please.

    case WM_PAINT:
        BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
 EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
 return 0;

Comment: WM_PAINT isn't a real message - it's just a flag on the window that says it has invalidated regions (WM_PAINT never handled.)  As long as that flag is present, WM_PAINT will be generated.

Comment: there isnt another way to acomplish that? looks like this will just add more processing to my program instead if just discard the message.

Comment: looks like you can also do it by forwarding wm_paint to DefWindowProc but it probably does the same thing

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you are processing the **WM_PAINT** correctly.

By this I mean make sure you are calling **BeginPaint** and **EndPaint** from inside the **WM_PAINT** message, otherwise you will be confusing *Windows* into thinking your application still needs to be painted.

Answer (score 0):

May be there is always a message waiting ?

Answer (score 0):

PeekMessage will return 0 only if there are no messages in the message queue. Since there are messages to be dispatched in the message queue, it is returning a non-zero value and your else condition is never executed.

Comment: I guess he is asking about this - why doesn't it ever happen that there're no messages left.